# Prove that there is no integer $k$ with $P(k)=8$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, contest-math

> Let $P(x)= x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0$be a polynomial with
>   integral coefficients. Suppose that there exists four distinct
>   integers $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ with $P(a)=P(b)=P(c)=P(d)=5$. Prove that
>   there is no integer $k$ with $P(k)=8$

My approach:

Define $Q(x)=P(x)-5$; consequently, the $deg(Q) \geq 4$ and $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are roots for $Q$. By the Viete's Theorem, $Q(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)$ ($deg(Q) = 4$), then consider there exists $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $Q(k)=3$. As $(k-a)(k-b)(k-c)(k-d)=3$, then there exist two factors amongst four so that they are equals to $1$ or $-1$. It is therefore necessary that two zeros are equal **(Contradiction)**. The case where the degree of $Q$ is greater than $4$ is very similar to our argument.

Could you tell me if my argument valid?

I already know there are similar questions on the WebSite. However, I don't ask the same thing. I therefore consider that a new issue worth to be presented.

Comment: Yes. Possibly more directly stated: $Q(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)Q_0(x)$ and any factoring of $3$ into five integers must have at most four difference factors, $1,-1,$ and one of $3,-3$. So two of $k-a,k-b,k-c,k-d$ must be equal.

Comment: $Q_0(x)$ is juste when $deg(Q)>4$?

Comment: The right idea, not as clearly put as it might be. Note that even when the degree is $4$, the polynomial might have shape $k*x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)$. You can handle degree $4$ and $\gt 4$ simultaneously.

Comment: @J.G - $Q_0$ can be a constant, so Thomas's version of the argument covers $\operatorname{deg}(Q) = 4$ as well. This is still your argument. He is just giving a clearer way of stating it.